# Replicating exp function with multiple inputs from R in python

Tags: python, r, exp

I am attempting to replicate an R script in python, and have come across an exponential function that I do not understand:

```
exp(-var1-var2-var3)
```

If I were to use 0.8, 1.2, and 0.3 as variables here, R would give me the answer `0.1002588`. However, I do not know how this is arrived at. I understand that the equivalent of exp in python is `**`, and know how to replicate this function with only one number as input but I see no way to do this with multiple numbers. I have tried `-var1**-var2**-var3`, which gives me `-1.235241`.

How do I interpret this function, and what would the equivalent python code be for this?

Comment: Have you tried `math.exp(-var1-var2-var3)` in python? The `**` in python is how you do exponents, but the `exp()` function in particular (in R, python, and math in general) refers to a *specific* exponent -- the constant e to whatever is in the parentheses

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran the `exp` function with the exact same values and it outputs the right result:

```
from math import exp

# 0.8, 1.2, and 0.3 as variables here, R would give me the answer 0.1002588.
var1 = 0.8
var2 = 1.2
var3 = 0.3
res = exp(-var1-var2-var3)

print (res)
OUT: 0.10025884372280375
```

Comment: Thank you! That gives me the right answer, and efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

The function exp means e**(-var1-var2-var3)

You can translate from R to python by using math or numpy:

```
import numpy as np
import math


var1=0.8
var2=1.2
var3=0.3
print('numpy:',np.exp(-var1-var2-var3))
print('math:',math.exp( -var1-var2-var3 ))
```

The output of the following code will be

```
numpy: 0.10025884372280375
math: 0.10025884372280375
```